# Objective C, Trim a float

Tags: ios, nsnumber

I have `float` like `3500,435232123`. All I want to know if exists (in Objective C) a function that let me keep just the last 4 digits in my case is 2123.

Comment: is your no is 3500.435232123? then 4 digit decimal should be 4352 not 2123 if it so you can use     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f",3500.435232123]; 
[

Comment: Why do you want to trim the float?

Comment: First, don't use float. Float has only 7 digits precision, so it's no good at all if your number is 3500,435232123. Use double. "Last four digits" = 2123 leads to badly defined results. What if the number was 3500,4352321230 ? Which is the same number, but the last four digits are 2130. And anyway, if you display _any_ floating point number with infinite precision, then it is either an integer or it ends with a 5, because floating point numbers are _binary_. So the result is _never_ 2123.

Comment: What are the "four last digits" of pi? Not every float has "last digits".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSNumberFormatter

```
NSNumberFormatter *format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
[format setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[format setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
[format setMaximumFractionDigits:4];
[format setMinimumFractionDigits:4];

string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[format stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:65.50055]] ;
```

Or simply

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.04f", floatValue];
```

If you want only last four digits, convert the float to a string

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", floatValue];
```

and get the last four characters

```
NSString *lastFour = [string substringFromIndex: [string length] - 4];
```

Comment: Yes but the number is still showing, I want just 4 digits after point, without left side. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It you want to get the decimal part, you can do x - floor(x). For instance:

```
float x = 3500,435232123;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.04f", x - floor(x)];
```

And to get 4 decimal digits do what Fawad Masud says.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such function, as far as i know. But here is a way to achieve exactly what you want.

First you have to round it to four digits after point:

```
NSString *exampleString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.04f", valueToRound];
```

Then you get the location for the comma inside the `exampleString`:

```
NSRange commaRange = [valueString rangeOfString:@","];
```

Finally you create the `finalString` with the values from that `NSRange`. The substring starts at `commaRange.location+commaRange.length`because thats the index directly after the comma.

```
NSString *finalString = [valueString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(commaRange.location+commaRange.length,valueString.length-commaRange.location-commaRange.length)];
```

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I think is no predefined function for that.

and the solution i thought of is:

```
float floatNum = 3500.435232123;
```

converting `float` number to string and trim/substring the string, like for example:

```
NSString *stringFloat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", floatNum];
NSString *newString = [stringFloat substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(stringFloat.length - 4, stringFloat.length)];

NSLog(@"%@", newString);
```

another is something like:

```
NSString *stringFloat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", floatNum];

//separates the floating number to 
arr[0] = whole number
arr[1] = decimals

NSArray *arr=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
```

since you just want to work on the decimal, i think `arr[1]` is what you need..

```
NSString *stringDecimals = (NSString *)arr[1];

if ( stringDecimals.length > 4) //check the length of the decimals then cut if exceeds 4 character..
{
    stringDecimals = [stringDecimals substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(stringDecimals.length - 4, stringDecimals.length)];
}

NSLog(@"stringDecimals: %@", stringDecimals);
```